# ClassNotFound Exception in Reflection created by Class name

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am facing difficulty with the below code. I need to create object through reflection by class name in Java but it throws below error while compiling.

```
// Class where package name with class is coming 
public class PickAdapter<T> {
    Object mObject;

    public T read(Element element, String classOfName) {
        try {
            Class mClass = Class.forName(classOfName);
            mObject = mClass.newInstance();
            Field[] fd = mClass.getDeclaredFields();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (T) mObject;
    }
}
```

Error in Logcat:

```
 10-28 17:12:54.619 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    10-28 17:12:55.771 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: class com.harpz.htmlee.model.MUser
    10-28 17:12:55.771 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    10-28 17:12:55.771 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
    10-28 17:12:55.771 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at com.harpz.htmleetim.reflection.PickAdapter.read(PickAdapter.java:22)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at com.harpz.htmleetim.Htmlee.fromHtml(Htmlee.java:25)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at com.harpz.htmleetim.Htmlee.fromHtml(Htmlee.java:19)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at com.harpz.htmleetim.Htmlee.fromHtml(Htmlee.java:13)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at com.harpz.htmlee.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    10-28 17:12:55.772 20743-20743/com.harpz.htmlee W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using reflection

- To load a class using reflection you need to ensure, that the wanted class is available in your [Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).
- In case you are developing an Android-App you need to include external packages into your apps library path.
- To load the class you need to specify the fully qualified class name, that means including the package name, e.g. `com.example.packageName.ClassName`

#### Regarding your problem.

So from your provided log output i can see that you try to load the class `com.harpz.htmlee.model.MUser`

But, as the error message suggests, you try to load the class with the name `class com...`.

Remove the preceding **class** (+ whitespace) keyword within the passed `classOfName` variable.

#### Code improvements

Moreover, i would advise you to change the `mObject` attribute into a locale variable within the `read` Method, as your usage (bases on your given snippet) is only within this method.

Furthermore, the `return` statement should be located within the `try`-block as it would never be reached in case of any exception.

So the code improvements would look like this:

```
public class PickAdapter<T> {

    public T read(Element element, String classOfName) {
        Object mObject;

        try {
            Class mClass = Class.forName(classOfName);
            mObject = mClass.newInstance();
            Field[] fd = mClass.getDeclaredFields();
            return (T) mObject;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} // end of class
```